# How do I use the IOCTL System Call to disable keypress echo and buffering?

Tags: c

I know it has to do with the struct termios but I can't figure it out by reading the man page.  My goal is that whenever a button is pushed on the keyboard it will be read without hitting enter and it will not be printed on the screen of my program.  Obviously both of these are important for creating a game.  Thank You!

Comment: Do you really have to use `ioctl(2)`? It's easier (and a better idea) to use `tcsetattr(3)` and `cfmakeraw(3)`. Do you have any special-purpose requirement that forces you to use `ioctl(2)`?

Comment: If you use `ioctl()`, you are into totally system-dependent territory.  The behaviour is not standardized; the notations used on System A may be completely different from the notations using on a different System B.  Use the POSIX functions if you can (try `man termios`).

Comment: Something like that.  ncurses conditionally compiles to use the POSIX functions if available, but supposedly (no recent platforms need it) degrades gracefully to termio and sgtty (ymmv).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example based on [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=225713&page=2&p=1335772#post1335772):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct termios old, new;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old);          // get current settings
    new = old;                              // create a backup
    new.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);        // disable line buffering and feedback
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new); // set our new config

    printf("Reading 5 characters without local echo...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char x = getchar();
        printf("[%c] ", x);
    }
    printf("\nRestoring terminal config\n");
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is fine, but the OP asked for an `ioctl` version.

Comment: strace the binary, and you'll see the ioctl, I think.