# How to 'silently' get user input from a terminal on Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, input, nasm, tty

I need to get user input skipping every second consonant in it. So every second consonant **should *not* be printed out** (not just deleted in some process after hitting Enter).

I've got a task from my teacher in assembler language. Currently I'm using NASM on Linux and would like to stick to it.

The problem is that I need to 'overload' user input interrupt and in it I should be able to process that input (skip every second consonant). I've searched the Net and didn't find any suiting answers. Not how to 'catch' user input before buffering and printing it out, nor the way to read a single character without printing it in terminal.

I would like to see an example of replacing (or modifying) the standard input interrupt system call. That would be the ideal case.

The second option is to make your own type of 'handler' getting each char one by one without echoing it and than handling things like Backspace and Enter myself. Just like `getch()` in Windows C does. (or 0x16 BIOS interrupt).

Comment: Translate [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810223/547981) into assembly.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're interpreting the assignment correctly?  Likely you're supposed to read input, then print a filtered copy of it.  What you want requires other POSIX TTY system calls to set the terminal to no-echo or even raw mode, if you're reading from a tty.  e.g. `./my_program < input_file` would work too.

Comment: No, it should work like this: 
User: *Presses R*
Terminal: R
User: *Presses f*
Terminal: R
User: *Presses z*
Terminal: Rz
And so on...

Comment: @Jester I'll try to, thank you

Comment: If you want to do that, then do what Jester suggested: disable echo and print only the characters that you want on screen

Comment: Yes, I see how it works. Now I need to translate it to NASM. Wish me best of lucks :D

Comment: How do I use getchar in NASM? It says that getchar is undefined reference (I included it as extern too)

Comment: Make sure you link with libc. Or you can just use a `read` system call with size 1.

Comment: Note that there is not “interrupt” or “handler” you can hook or modify.  UNIX (and Linux) doesn't work this way.  Instead, as Jester said, you need to reconfigure the terminal subsystem *termios* to not echo text typed by the user.  In addition to the answer Jester linked, I advice you to carefully read the Linux manpages `man 3 termios` and `man 4 tty_ioctl` which explain how the termios subsystem works and how to configure it without the libc.  Keep in mind that this is a somewhat advanced task to do in assembly and you need to manually build the right structures by looking at the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I use to retrieve a single keystroke. Keep in mind, functions keys, arrows and others like HOME, PGDN etc return more than one byte and for that reason I read up to 8 bytes so what's left in the input buffer won't become an artifact of the next write. This snippet was designed as a response system to things like;

> Continue [Y/N]

Calling process would read character returned in AL. If it's 0x1b (27 dec / ESC) then we know it's one of the extended keys. As an example, F1 would return 0x504f1b in EAX.

```
USE64

      sys_read      equ      0
      sys_write     equ      1
      sys_ioctl     equ     16

      %define      ICANON      2
      %define        ECHO      8
      %define      TCGETS      0x5401
      %define      TCPUTS      0X5402

            section    .text
    ; =============================================================================
    ; Accept a single key press from operator and return the result that may be
    ; up to 5 bytes in length.

    ;    LEAVE: RAX = Byte[s] returned by SYS_READ
    ; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

      %define   c_lflag     rdx + 12
      %define      keys     rbp +  8
      %define      MASK     ICANON | ECHO

      STK_SIZE  equ 56              ; Room for 36 byte termios structure

      QueryKey:

            xor     eax, eax
            push    rax             ; This is where result will be stored.

            push    rbp
            mov     rbp, rsp
            sub     rsp, STK_SIZE

            push    r11             ; Modified by SYSCALL
            push    rbx
            push    rdx
            push    rcx
            push    rdi
            push    rsi             ; With size of 56, stack is now QWORD aligned

            mov     edi, eax            ; Equivalent to setting EDI to STDIN
            mov     esi, TCGETS
            lea     rdx, [rbp-STK_SIZE] ; Points to TERMIOS buffer on stack
            mov      al, sys_ioctl
            syscall

            lea     rbx, [c_lflag]
            and     byte [rbx], ~(MASK)
            inc     esi                 ; RSI = TCPUTS
            push    rsi
            mov      al, sys_ioctl
            push    rax
            syscall

       ; Wait for keypress from operator.

            lea     rsi, [keys]         ; Set buffer for input
            push    rdx
            mov     edx, 8              ; Read QWORD bytes max
            mov      al, sys_read
            syscall

NOTE: The code you need could go here

            pop     rdx                 ; Points back to TERMIOS
            pop     rax
            pop     rsi                 ; TCPUTS again
            or      byte [rbx], MASK
            syscall

            pop     rsi
            pop     rdi
            pop     rcx
            pop     rdx
            pop     rbx
            pop     r11

            leave
            pop        rax              ; Return up to 8 characters
            ret
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to obfuscate your code with `xor eax,eax` at the top and `mov al, imm8` later on; the required system calls are already complicated and obscure enough.  Also, if stdin isn't a TTY, the first syscall will return `-ENOTTY` and the second system call will be made with RAX=FFFF...?? and return -ENOSYS.  At least using `mov eax, sys_read` would still `read(0, buf, 8)` in that case.

Comment: Putting the registers into the `%define` also makes it harder to read the code, IMO.  At first I was assuming that `lea     rbx, [c_lflag]` was static storage (and that you'd forgotten `default rel`).  `lea  rbx, [rdx + c_lflag]` would be more readable IMO, with just an EQU constant for struct layout stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes Obfuscation is a paradigm that although I don't think is totally unwarranted, but still a work in progress to evaluate when is it really necessary. In the context of your critique, I'm saving one byte versus `push 0` and then later `mov eax,sys_ioctl`. I am leaning toward more detailed comments to make the intent much clearer.

Comment: The result is making it harder to read, even though obfuscation isn't the *motivation*.  IMO just use `mov` and leave optimization to the reader.  If you're optimizing, don't use `rbp` at all.  And there's no particular benefit to putting the output buffer above the saved RBP.  You could just `push rax` / `mov rsi, rsp` right before `syscall`.  If 1 or more bytes are read, it will overwrite the non-zero low byte of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you, @Shift_Left! It works like a charm! 
However I can't figure out check if inputed symbol was a Backspace (0x08 is the code, I guess) or Enter. Can you help me to figure that out, please?
Other characters are working well for me.

Comment: @NikitaAndrasovich whenever the character returned in AL is not 0x1B (ESC) then a single byte is returned and it will be the keycode for the corresponding key such as 0x8 for backspace and 0x0D (13) for ENTER.

Comment: @Shift_Left, I managed to catch enter by using
`cmp rax, 10; je done_input`
Using new line code 10. But doing
`cmp al, 0x8;  je backspace_pressed`
doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @NikitaAndrasovich Sorry, wasn't thinking about Linux, AL = 0x7f on backspace. Keep in mind, unless AL = 0x1B there is no need to test anything greater than 1 byte.

Comment: Oh, I just found a solution by comparing rax to code 127 (which is DELETE in ASCII table). And it works perfectly now!
Anyway, glad you were here to help, @Shift_Left! Thanks!